# select and delete query based on older entries

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Excel sheet that is pushing data to an Access database using ADO. It is essentially putting invoices into a database. Sometimes I will revise my invoice and therefore the database will end up with the same invoice twice. I need to make a select and delete query that will find duplicates based on the invoice number, and delete the older version of the invoice (older record), for a simple example:

```
   id  invoice#    total  item    datestamp
    1      1234  456.29$  shoes   06/06/2016 03:51
    2      1234   78.58$  boots   06/06/2016 03:51
    3      1234   22.74$  scarf   06/06/2016 03:51
    4      1234  539.34$  shoes   06/07/2016 12:44
    4      1234   66.24$  pants   06/07/2016 12:44
```

As you can see row 4 and 5 are my new invoice for this customer. I want every previous order of the same invoice # to be deleted. *Please note: they are not actually duplicates, only the invoice number is duplicated*. The query needs to see dupliactes based on invoice number and criteria sees dates older than the most recent date.

At that point it is way beyond me. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: I have to say that it would be worthwhile trying this yourself. You've clearly defined the task that needs to be completed, now all you need is to research the SQL commands to finish the job. You'll need an Access query to do the job, most likely in SQL view. Perhaps the answer here is also *not* to be destructive - you seem to have a good audit trail of what has gone before. Why not simply select the most recent invoices based on their dates?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a correlated aggregate subquery in `WHERE` clause:

```sql
DELETE * 
FROM InvoiceTable
WHERE NOT datestamp IN 
   (SELECT Max(datestamp)
    FROM InvoiceTable sub
    WHERE sub.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceTable.InvoiceNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said, try being conservative and not deleting. Instead, select rows that are based on the maximum date stamp for a given invoice number:

```sql
SELECT 
    invoices.id, invoices.invoice, invoices.total, invoices.item, invoices.datestamp 
FROM 
    invoices 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        id, MAX(datestamp) AS maxdate 
    FROM 
        invoices 
    GROUP BY 
        id) lastinv 
    ON invoices.id = lastinv.id AND 
       invoices.datestamp = lastinv.maxdate
```

This is untested code, but should, pretty much do what you want. All you have to do is mangle it into Microsoft Access, as this is T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the answers but these are still very beyond me.  I know nothing of access. For some reason i would find this simple in excel but don[t even know where to start in access. Ideally i don't even wwant it to be a VBA or SQl based solution (which seems like your answers) but just doing a complex find duplicates query in the access designer that shows duplicates, BUT ONLY the duplicates of a newer date./ So sorry for my ignorance